# Is there an equivalence of MapRGB for a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to color individual pixels in a `BufferedImage` (TYPE_INT_RGB) using `setRGB()`, but I'm not sure how to format the RGB values. I want the result as a single integer. Is there a method that will take three `int` values (red, green, blue) and return a correctly formatted integer for `setRGB()`?

Comment: Crap I have bad grammar.

Comment: I have edited your question; please revert if unwanted. Also, you need a comma after _Crap_. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have ints `r`, `g`, and `b`, you can do:

```
int pixel = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

This is because pixels in a `BufferedImage` are 4-byte ints.  The 4-bytes represent Alpha, Red, Green, and Blue, in that order.  So, if you shift red left by two bytes and green left by one byte, then bitwise-or `r`, `g`, and `b`, you will get a valid pixel to use with `setRGB()`.

Comment: The answer provided below shows a deeper knowledge of the Java APIs, but I gave +1 here because with this answer you'll find your way around almost any graphics/image processing library

Answer (score 4):

```
new Color(red, green, blue).getRGB();
```